# How to use API rate limit for any authenticated users?

Tags: laravel

For example: An API route that I want to allow 500 requests ( from any  **logged in**  user ) per 15 minutes

- logged in  **user A**  requests the API => 499 remained
- logged in  **user B**  requests the API => 498 remained

*API rate-limit will be reset after 15 minutes

How to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `limit` and `limit_created_at` column to user table in database, and create middleware with similar code:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthLimitMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $user = Auth::user(); //or your get user method

        DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->increment('limit');

        if ($user->limit_created_at + 60 * 15 > time()) {
           $user->limit = 0;
           $user->limit_craeted_at = now();
           $user->save();
        }

        if ($user->limit > 500) {
             throw new ConflictHttpException('limit is more for 500')
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now register middlware in kernel file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 ...
  'limit' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthLimitMiddleware::class,
];
```

And use it on route:

```
Route::get('some/route')->middleware('auth', 'limit');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was thinking of doing it using laravel throttle middleware.. but this works for me.